# What database product would support 8000 columns, unlimited row size and no character limit on text fields?

Tags: database-recommendation

Imagine a spreadsheet that's as wide in column count as it is long in row count - say 10,000 rows x 10,000 columns. That's what I'm trying to find an equivalent DB product to achieve. The column headings also stretch out to about 500 characters but the corresponding cell values on all but 2 of the columns (the first two) are either `1` or `0` (translating a binary data file). So, column 1 and 2 in the structure have conventional string and floating point values and short column names. And then everything else is a `1` or a `0` with the bloated column heading text values taking up more space than the corresponding row values.

I have tried SQLite, Postgres, MariaDB and MySQL but I keep running into limits either on the number of columns, on the row size or on the column width (mainly because of the headings).

Is there any database product flexible enough to support a single table with all of these features?

Comment: Welcome to the DBA.SE community. You might want to outline what your are actually wanting to achieve. A DB redesign might be a plausible solution. However, if you are just looking for a product to transform the data from product A to B, then you might want to consider having a consultant look into your situation. 10'000 rows isn't much of an issue, as current DBMS can support millions or trillions of rows. The number of columns is however a limiting factor. Please consider [editing](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/324852/edit) your question and providing more details. Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to reconsider your design. It sounds like you need to redesign your table into a long skinny design, but without really understanding what your columns are it's hard to say. For example, if you have a bunch of attribute of products per row, and each column represents true/false for each attribute, then you transform that into an EAV design: Product, Attribute, ProductAttribute.

Answer (score 2):

We have 2 options:

- **NoSQL** [Google Bigtable](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/schema-design#:%7E:text=Bigtable%20tables%20are%20sparse%2C%20and,of%20256%20MB%20per%20row.): can support millions of columns in a table, and a maximum row size of 256 MB. It does not support SQL queries, joins, or multi-row transactions.
- **RDBMS** [BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#:%7E:text=A%20table%2C%20query%20result%2C%20or%20view%20definition%20can,have%20up%20to%2010%2C000%20columns.&text=The%20total%20query%20result%20sizes,information%2C%20see%20BigQuery%20Omni%20limitations.): can support till 10,000 columns and a maximum row size of 100 MB

Answer (score 0):

> support 8000 columns, unlimited row size and no character limit on text fields?...Is there any database product flexible enough to support a single table with all of these features?

No, probably not. These are pretty unreasonable and unrealistic requirements for a database system.

Even a spreadsheet (Excel for example, but could be any) file will have a limit on character length. SQL Server caps out at around 2 GB on the `VARCHAR(MAX)` and `NVARCHAR(MAX)` fields. 2 GB of `VARCHAR` characters is a total of ~2 billion characters. If you have a single field / data point that needs more than 2 billion characters, then something is wrong with your design and it should be re-architected.

A table with 8,000 columns is untenable. It very likely should be split into multipe realistic tables that can be better maintained. SQL Server's restrictions on number of columns in a table are capped at 1,024 which is pretty insane in itself.